# What is the formula used to calculate the monthly insurance pay for a loan?

Tags: applications

So, basically, I need to create a loan calculator in the Excel and one of the points is insurance bonus, it's also paid monthly, but I don't know the formula? I only know that it depends on the age and the remaining amount of loan. How to calculate it in Excel knowing that the payment will be done monthly so that means that the age changes when it's passed 12 months, and I have no idea how to change it as well. Can someone please help?

Comment: How is this related to mathematics?

Comment: @copper.hat It is related to actuarial science, so I assumed it must have some relation to mathematics?

Comment: Maybe try https://money.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can have a detailed explanation with Excel formula here

[Monthly Payment Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula)